# Two bash aliases, same function

Tags: bash

I have a very simple function

```
function filefinder
{
  FILE=$1; test -f $FILE || FILE=`find . -name $FILE`; /usr/bin/geany $FILE
}
alias geany=filefinder
```

But I would like other editors to use the same function. How can I do that? Say, I would like to add `alias nano=filefinder`. Obviously I wouldn't like to hardwire either geany or nano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
function filefinder
    {
        FILE=$2; ED=$1; test -f $FILE || FILE=`find . -name $FILE`; /usr/bin/$ED $FILE;
    }
    alias geany="filefinder geany"
    alias gedit="filefinder gedit"
    alias nano="filefinder nano"
```

I assumed your distro keeps all the execs in /usr/bin

Comment: I will accept this if something more elegant doesn't surface.

Comment: In theory, you can use $FUNCNAME to get the name of a function that is being called, or ${FUNCNAME[0]} to get the same thing, or ${FUNCNAME[1]} to get the name of the function that called you.  So, in theory, you could do what you wanted by using ${FUNCNAME[1]} instead of ED=$1 in the script above if you use 'function' instead of 'alias' to define your editor-specific variants.  In practice, I could not get that to work, so I think the answer presented by Met is probably best.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this sort of thing is with the variables that are commonly used to hold the name of the user's preferred editor.

```
function filefinder {
  editor=${VISUAL:-$EDITOR}; editor=${editor:-emacs}; FILE=$1; test -f "$FILE" || FILE=$(find . -name "$FILE"); "$editor" "$FILE"
}
```

This follows what Bash does when you use the `readline` function `edit-and-execute-command`.

If `$VISUAL` is set use it, if not use `$EDITOR`. It that's not set, use `emacs` as the fallback (you could use something else if you want, of course).

Comment: Dennis gets extra points for being the first person to point out that you should be quoting `$FILE`.

Answer (score 0):

How about an environment variable?:

```
function filefinder
{
  if [ -z "$MY_EDITOR" ];then 
    echo "MY_EDITOR is not set";
  else  
    FILE=$1; test -f $FILE || FILE=`find . -name $FILE`; $MY_EDITOR $FILE
  fi
}

alias myedit=filefinder
```

Comment: How this will work for two editors? I was looking for something like `$0  $FILE` but that doesn't work.

Comment: chx - for something like this, you would do `MY_EDITOR=vim filefinder file.txt`. If you used EDITOR instead, it may be already set to the user's preferred editor.